# Setting a cookie from a php post form

Tags: php, post, cookies

Im trying to get a php form to either autopopulate a user ID field from a cookie or if it is a  new pc then give the user the option of 'remember me'. when I manually add a cookie and then load the form page it populates the user box correctly, but I cant seem to set a cookie when it is posted from the form itself.

Code from the php form:

```
<form action="./post_cookies.php" method="post" id="HOME">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><i>Whats your username:</i></li>
           <li><i><input type="text" size="40" name="User_ID" 

           <?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
  echo "value=\"" . $_COOKIE["user"] . "\"</i></li>";
else
  echo "placeholder=\"12345\"></i></li>";
?> 
            <li><i>Remember me: <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="remember" VALUE="1"> Yes</i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div id="nav" style="text-align:center;">
        <ul>
            <li><i><button form="HOME" type=submit style="width:200px;height:40px">Submit</button></i></li>
        </form>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

this form posts to 'post_cookies.php' the code is:

```
   <?php
// creating a variable to store the timestamp in
$posttime = time();

// if the remember me checkbox returns a 1 then add the users, username as a cookie

if($_POST[remember]==1)
{   
    setcookie('user', $_POST[User_ID], $posttime + 3600);        // Sets the cookie 
}

// this is where the data base connection would go

header("Location: http://www.domain.com/index.php");
?>
```

The idea is that if the 'remember me' is checked then the post_cookies.php will set a cookie  with the usersID.

I cant see where post_cookies.php is going wrong and not setting a cookie.
any assistance is greatly appreciated.

thanks!
Mathew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ($_POST['remember'] == 1) {   
    setcookie('user', $_POST['User_ID'], $posttime + 3600);        // Sets the cookie 
}
```

The array key is in quotes. Try that

Same with

```
$_POST['User_ID']
```

Also

```
echo "value=\"" . $_COOKIE["user"] . "\"</i></li>";
```

Is missing a closing `>` before the `</i>`

Comment: Still cant get it to load a cookie, I amended both files and put: '<?php
// Print a cookie
echo $_COOKIE["user"];

?>' to try and see if I could read the presented cookie, but still blank.

Comment: If I use $_POST in if condition then setcookie inside if block doesn't sets cookie although it returns true. Very peculiar thing. Sucking me.